# How to find time complexity of the following recursive code?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, time-complexity

I am trying to find runtime complexity of the following program but no luck. I believe that this program will run in exponential time as we are recursively calling the function twice in the worst case and every call in-turn is called twice. But i am not able to derive it completely.

I have taken this code from one of the solution given in leetcode for finding [regular expression match](https://leetcode.com/problems/regular-expression-matching/solution/).

```
public boolean isMatch(String text, String pattern) {
    if (pattern.isEmpty()) {
          return text.isEmpty();
    }
    boolean first_match = (!text.isEmpty() &&
                           (pattern.charAt(0) == text.charAt(0) || pattern.charAt(0) == '.'));

    if (pattern.length() >= 2 && pattern.charAt(1) == '*'){
        return (isMatch(text, pattern.substring(2)) ||
                (first_match && isMatch(text.substring(1), pattern)));
    } else {
        return first_match && isMatch(text.substring(1), pattern.substring(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a Complexity Analysis section in the [link](https://leetcode.com/problems/regular-expression-matching/solution/) you gave us...

Comment: I know... but i could not understand that explanation. That's why posted it here.